# Setting an Individual Media Folder for Django App

Tags: django, django-templates

Can I set up a folder in my Django app for local media, that is referenced with a tag similar to `{{ STATIC_URL }}`?

I have several JavaScript, CSS and image files set up in my static directory at the moment.  These files, however, are really local to my app and are not used by other apps in the Django site.  In some cases these other apps are managed by other people and, as a result, we may accidentally name both have a `site.js` - for example.

Is there a tag I can use to always point back to a root (relative to the app) media directory - for example, `{{ LOCAL_MEDIA }}/js/site.js`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common solution to this is the same as with the application templates: use a directory named for the app to namespace the static resources. Here the directory would look like

```
myapp/
    __init__.py
    models.py
    views.py
    static/
        myapp/
            js/site.js
            css/site.css
```

In the template they would be referenced with `{{ STATIC_URL }}` as usual

```
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}myapp/js/site.js"></script>
```

Comment: Shortly after posting I thought I might be pointed down this common "app name within a sub-directory of the app" philosophy.  I was hoping there was something a little craftier in this case.  Thank you!